# Photoshop: how to create this glitché effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, rgb, ios

This effect is from Glitché iOS app. I tried various methods from dissolve (move RGB layers, copying many layers of one pic), distortion filters and still don't get something close to these pictures.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a layer for every color step with a copy of the image.

Layers are scaled up from yellow to blue in equal steps.

Optionally the layers can be moved off center.

Color them each with Hue/Saturation with Colorize checked (also available as Adjustment Layer)

Blend them in Screen mode. Adjust intensity with layer transparency.

(The upper image looks like the girl was isolated from the background and added on top of the layer stack)

Comment: Thanks. It seems like this process requires a lot of manipulation and time. Its so sad that with iphone you can achieve it in a second of time(  how is this real, i dont get it.

Comment: @moon420 with flexibility comes also restrictions. But no i expect this to be a 3 minute task to make a action for PS. after that ist allways a one click solution. THough to be honest that why programmers exist.